# Installing Virtual Box on Solus: Linux kernel header files

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-kernel

I have a problem with installing the VirtualBox on Linux Solus.
When  I try to start it it gives me this error-message:

```
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
```

I have this version when typing uname -r

```
4.18.16-96.current
```

I am a Linux Newbie and I tried to fix this with reading other similar Questions but nothing works and I need it for work.

Hope someone can help, I would really appreciate it :)